# FindInstance—why doesn't it work with my expression?

Tags: equation-solving, performance-tuning

I want to find arbitrary solution of a system of equations:

```
Solve[
  p1*ai1*xi + Sqrt[p1*(1 - p1)]*ai2*yi + Sqrt[p1*(1 - p1)]*bi1*Conjugate[yi] - 
    (1 - p1)*bi2*xi == 0 && 
  Conjugate[ai1]*ai1 + Conjugate[bi1]*bi1 == 1 && 
  Conjugate[ai2]*ai2 + Conjugate[bi2]*bi2 == 1 &&
  Conjugate[ai2]*ai1 + Conjugate[bi2]*bi1 == 0 &&
  xi^2 + yi*Conjugate[yi] == 1 &&
  0 <= xi <= 1 && 0 <= p1 <= 1, 
  {ai1, ai2, bi1, bi2}]
```

Because the calculation was taking too long (after one hour still no output), I tried to set some values for xi`,`yi`and`p1`. None the less the calculation still is very slow. I don't get an answer after 30 minutes.
:

```
p1 = 0.5
yi = Sqrt[3]/2*Exp[2*I]
xi = 1/2
FindInstance[
      p1*ai1*xi + Sqrt[p1*(1 - p1)]*ai2*yi + Sqrt[p1*(1 - p1)]*bi1*Conjugate[yi] - 
        (1 - p1)*bi2*xi == 0 && 
      Conjugate[ai1]*ai1 + Conjugate[bi1]*bi1 == 1 && 
      Conjugate[ai2]*ai2 + Conjugate[bi2]*bi2 == 1 &&
      Conjugate[ai2]*ai1 + Conjugate[bi2]*bi1 == 0, 
      {ai1, ai2, bi1, bi2}]
```

Is my problem really so difficult? Can my code be improved so it run in a reasonable time?

Comment: Your posted code doesn't run and returns an error. Have you tried clearing all definitions in your notebook (e.g. ``Clear["Global`*"]``) before running your code?

Comment: I have changed the code, so it now should not produce any error.

Comment: If you want to find any instance, including real solutions, constraining the domain to `Reals` in `FindInstance` gives `{{ai1 -> -0.347985, ai2 -> -0.9375, bi1 -> 0.9375, bi2 -> -0.347985}}` in no time.

Comment: Ok, thanks. But what if my initial conditions are not real, for example: yi = Sqrt[3]/2*Exp[2*I] (which is in general the case)?

Comment: But you see that the broader the domain the more difficult the task you are requesting. Other solutions:
`{Integers, {{ai1 -> 1, ai2 -> 0, bi1 -> 0, 
   bi2 -> 1}}}, {Primes, {}}, {Rationals, {{ai1 -> -1, ai2 -> 0, 
   bi1 -> 0, bi2 -> -1}}}`

Comment: Yes, it is clear to me. But I would like to find a solution to upper problem (so with general p1,xi,yi), so the solution (if it exists?) will be in general complex. But it looks as if the Mathematica cannot solve this problem...

Comment: Well then given that we don't even know if the solution exists in complexes , I don't see which kind of answer do you expect. The questions you ask are not answerable.